Left invariant 1-form of $\text{GL}(\mathbb{R})$, M. Fecko
I'm reading Chapter 11 of Differential geometry and Lie Groups for Physicists by M. Fecko.
I'm trying to get a grasp of what left-invariant tensor fields look like by understanding an example of $\text{GL}(\mathbb{R^n})$ given in this textbook. (p. 218 Exercise 11.1.9)
In this problem, the coordinate is $x^i_j$, each component of the matrix. The textbook also uses the variable $x$ to refer to a point in the Lie group but I use $A, B,..$ here.
In my understanding, the procedure to find left invariant 1-forms is the following.
Define $L_A: G \rightarrow G, B \mapsto A B$. Then, for $\alpha (B) = \alpha^i_j(B) dx^j_i \in \Omega^1(G)$, the pullback is
$$
L_A^*: \Omega^1(G) \rightarrow \Omega^1(G) \\
\alpha^i_j(B) dx^j_i \mapsto \alpha^i_j(AB) A^k_i dx^j_k
$$
where $B$ is a variable on $G$.
The condition for left-invariance is $(L_A^* \alpha)(B) = \alpha(A^{-1}B)$ (this is what I'm not very sure about but I assume many textbooks mean this by slightly abusing the notation as $L_A^* \alpha = \alpha.$)
But the textbook says the condition leads to
$$
\alpha^i_k (AB) A^k_j = \alpha^i_j (B)
$$
which is not what I have. I get this only if I impose $(L_A^* \alpha)(B) = \alpha(B)$, but pullback maps a cotangent space to another so this condition doesn't look right.
There is also an analogous exercise on vector fields (p. 219, 11.1.10) but it also seems to impose a similar condition.
Where did I go wrong?
Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Left invariance means precisely that $L_A^* \alpha = \alpha$, which of course means that the two forms take the same value at any $B$. Note that if you pull back something to $B$, you must have $AC=B$, and so you’re pulling back from $C=A^{-1}B$, not $AB$.

Thank you for the comment. I think I figured it out now.

I figured out where my confusion comes from thanks to the comment.
$L_A^* \alpha = \alpha$ literally means for any $B$, $(L_A^* \alpha) (B) = \alpha (B)$, so the condition is right.
The reason why I thought it means $(L_A^* \alpha) (B) = \alpha (A^{-1} B)$ was because on p.216, the author says the definition of left invariance is $T(gh) = L_{g*} T(h)$ which doesn't mean $T(gh) = (L_{g*} T)(h)$.
Rather $L_{g*}$ in $T(gh) = L_{g*} T(h)$ is a map from $L_{g*}: T_h G \rightarrow T_{gh} G$ instead of $\mathcal{T}^p_q(M) \rightarrow \mathcal{T}^p_q(M)$.
